# Using socket in Android development

Tags: java, android, sockets, kotlin

I have been looking around for a guide on how to implement socket in android development but could not find any. I am currently recalling my API on activity created to ensure that data is updated for my app.

Can anyone assist with a guide to help achieve real time update with socket on android.

Comment: check this if it's helpful https://dev.to/medaymentn/creating-a-realtime-chat-app-with-android--nodejs-and-socketio-4o55

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a powerful library called `SOCKET.IO` that you could use for this purpose. It supports multiple languages for both backend and client applications. Please check [this link](https://socket.io/) for more info and also [here](https://medium.com/@divyeshmali236/working-with-socket-io-in-android-6a2671c1cc19) is an android example.